# How to traverse AST tree

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to create an static analysis for Groovy. As a POC for my superiors I'm just trying to parse simple code and detect SQL injections, which are the easiest kind to spot. I did it successfully on Python, which is my main language, but my company mostly uses Grails (on Groovy).

This is what I have so far:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilder

public class SecurityCheck extends CodeVisitorSupport {
    void visitBlockStatement(BlockStatement statement) {
        println "NEW BLOCK STATEMENT:"
        println statement.getText();
        //keep walking...
        statement.getStatements().each { ASTNode child ->
            println "CHILD FOUND: "
            println child.getText();
            child.visit(this)
        }
    }
}

def code = new File('groovy_source.groovy').text // get the code from the source file
def AstBuilder astBuilder = new AstBuilder()  // build an instance of the ast builder
def ast = astBuilder.buildFromString(CompilePhase.CONVERSION, code) // build from string when the compiler converts from tokens to AST
def SecurityCheck securityCheck = new SecurityCheck()  // create an instance of our security check class
println ast
println ast[0]
ast[0].visit(securityCheck)
```

The groovy_source.groovy file is very simple, containing only a minimal file with a super easy to spot vulnerability:

```
def post(id) {
   query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + id;
   result = sql.execute query
   return result;
}
```

It is my understanding that, as I'm inheriting from CodeVisitorSupport, this would just visit a BlockStatement and then, for each statement inside that statement, it would visit it using the method from the supper class.

Nevertheless, when I print the text from the BlockStatement, it is an empty string, and the for each method never even gets called (which I assume must mean the AST found no children for my block statement, even when the function definitively has statements inside it.

```
[org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement@363a52f[]]  // println ast
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement@363a52f[]  // println ast[0]
NEW BLOCK STATEMENT:
{  }  // println statement.getText()
```

Any help here would be tremendously appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I feel you, man. The way I learned how to traverse that tree was a lot of experimenting with reflection, decompling .class files and using debugger just to analyze the stack. As far as I was searching (mind that it was like 2 years ago) there is no online doc, so if you're just looking for the way, try figuring API yourself.

Comment: Wow, that sounds discouraging. Do you have any working example of how you ended up doing it? Or at least do you know where I can find the source code for the CodeVisitorSupport class?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/groovy/tree/master/src/main this is a good place to start, but a lot of sources are also on http://grepcode.com/ and that is more useful.

Comment: Also, I recommend using IntelliJ IDE, it has wonderful built-in support for *.class decompilation, it's really useful for this kind of stuff - you just browse the dependencies pane, find groovy-all, then browse for class you want, or navigate from code by inspection.

Comment: I'm using InteliJ and found its *.class decompilation somewhat useful. I guess I'll just have to read that code paying more attention to it this time. Thanks for the links!

Comment: Last, but not least, IntelliJ also gives you some support for automatic fetching of sources for maven dependencies that you have, so groovy-all should be available too - it's even better than decompiling, since you can often see groovy code instead of equivalent java code. Unfortunately, fetching of sources is dependent on many factors and doesn't always work.

Comment: I decided to split my tips into more comments for it to be easier to go thorugh (one solution per comment). Good luck with that. Also, feel free to contact me - my username here is my real name, and I have (name).(surname) GMail address. I'll be happy to help ;)

Comment: Dude, you're probably the best person ever, ever, ever. Thank you so much. I will try out all of these suggestions and I'll probably contact you on Monday. So helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I wasn't so hard in the end, but the horrible documentation doesn't make it easy. If you one to traverse the tree, you need to give the constructor the false boolean as a second argument, like this:

```
def ast = astBuilder.buildFromString(CompilePhase.CONVERSION, false, code)
```

Then you can use the visit* methods as you expect.